# I am new to test classes, how to cover this REST service

Tags: unit-test, rest-service

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/BLN_ASC_ScannedTickets/*')
    global with sharing class BLN_ASC_ScannedTickets{
    global static BLN_Mytickets_BAL ordersList {get ; set ;}
    global static BLN_ASC_Checkin.TotalList  TL {get ; set ;}


    @HttpPost  
    global static BLN_ASC_Checkin.TotalList doPost(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;  
        String OrderID = req.params.get('Order_Id');
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response; 
        List<BLN_ASC_Checkin.maincontainer> Mc = new List<BLN_ASC_Checkin.maincontainer> ();
   TL = new BLN_ASC_Checkin.TotalList ();
   //ord = new Ordersonly ();
    string eventid = req.params.get('Event_id');
    string Userid = req.params.get('User_id'); 
    String tics = '';
    ordersList = new BLN_Mytickets_BAL();
    Map<id,string> mapdemo  = new Map<id,string>();
    ordersList.orderId=OrderID;

   LIST<BLN_Mytickets_BAL.inncls>  inlists = ordersList.userTickets(Userid,eventid,'BLN_ASC_ScannedTickets','');

    for(BLN_Mytickets_BAL.inncls cls : inlists){
         BLN_ASC_Checkin.maincontainer nemain= new BLN_ASC_Checkin.maincontainer();
         nemain.orderInn =cls.orderInn;
         nemain.dt=cls.dt;
         nemain.ticketsInn =cls.ticketsInn ;
         nemain.cancelledTickets=cls.cancelledTickets;
          nemain.paymentInn=cls.paymentInn;
         nemain.orderItemInn =cls.orderItemInn ;
         nemain.orderPrice= cls.orderPrice;
         Mc.add(nemain);
    }




     TL.TotalLists= Mc;
     TL.isorder=ordersList.isorder;//to check from mobile wheteher it is a orderqrcode or badgeqrcode
      return TL;
      }

  }
```

[image: the uncovered part for loop ,is shown in the image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to populate `LIST<BLN_Mytickets_BAL.inncls>  inlists`.
I am not sure how your logic work but my guess is that you need to make `ordersList.userTickets(Userid,eventid,'BLN_ASC_ScannedTickets','')` return not empty list.

Comment: yes Artur Kępczyński,what you said is right. i need to make sure that ordersList.userTickets(Userid,eventid,'BLN_ASC_ScannedTickets','') return not empty list.

Comment: i wort the following code to cover that part of code

Comment: i am unable to post the code, anyway can u suggest me to do the same

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase it? I am not sure if I understand what is the problem for you....